# Extracting certain lines from a text file

Tags: python

So I have a text file from which I am trying to extract certain lines which contain a specific word. The lines are want are lines which contain the word HEIGHT, however there is another category in my text file called AVERAGEHEIGHT. So when I run this code it extracts all lines that contain both HEIGHT and AVERAGEHEIGHT, where as I am only interested in HEIGHT. Is there a way to fix this?

Here is my line of code for this

```
open('height.txt','w').writelines([ line for line in open("Test1.txt") if "HEIGHT" in line])
```

Thanks in advance for any advice on the matter.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can think of, without knowing the rest of your input, would be as follows:

```
open('height.txt','w').writelines([ line for line in open("Test1.txt") if "HEIGHT" in line and "AVERAGEHEIGHT" not in line])
```

EDIT:

```
open('height.txt','w').writelines([ line for line in open("Test1.txt") if "HEIGHT" in line and "AVERAGEHEIGHT" not in line and "TOTAL HEIGHT" not in line])
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense however it is not completely working for me. In reality there are two categories which I want to avoid (AVERAGEHEIGHT and TOTAL HEIGHT), and it is only working for AVERAGEHEIGHT and not TOTAL HEIGHT for some reason... strange

Comment: You never mentioned the restriction with TOTAL HEIGHT, see my edit

Comment: Yea even with that it is not recognizing it, I have copied it exactly as it is from the text file but it is still showing up, I do appreciate you trying to help though, thanks again.

Comment: Could you please post the file you're using, so that I can get a better idea of what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
with open('linestoread.txt') as f:
    our_lines = f.readlines()
    for l in our_lines:
        if 'HEIGHT' in l and not 'AVERAGEHEIGHT' in l: 
                with open('height.txt', 'a') as f:
                     f.writelines(l)
```